# Flutter container inside a container using a widget

Tags: flutter

I want to add  two boxes, one inside another. Here's my code and its not working for two boxes. how should I correct this. [doc UI](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FFBytCoqEa3AS9Q1Pxxht5qIG1rT5BYxybDXr49s-M0/edit?usp=sharing) in this doc you can see the UI I implement so far and the UI I want to be implement.

```
Widget DetailBox() => Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
  child:Column(
    children: [
      Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          color: Colors.white,
      ),
      // alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      height: 400,
      width: 300,


        child:   Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
          ),
          // alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          height: 100,
          width: 300,
      ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: by two boxes you mean purple and white one as seen in design ?

Comment: yess the purple and white boxes

Comment: Use a card and inside a Column and take two Container and both Container wrap to expanded and 1 expanded flex =1 and second flex 3

Comment: Try using Stack with Align

Comment: kindly can you provide any kind of code example please

Comment: you can use Stack for the other container and for the shape you can use 
the package called  flutter_custom_clippers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May it help you

```
 Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          ),
          elevation: 5,
          shadowColor: Colors.blue.shade200,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,

                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft:Radius.circular(25),topRight:Radius.circular(25))
                  ),


                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(

                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomRight:Radius.circular(25),bottomLeft:Radius.circular(25))
                  ),


                ),
              )
            ],
          ),

        ),
```

[image]

According to the design of the app, put the image in the bule  box.